# Can I ask questions about asking questions?

Tags: discussion

This is that type of question, but it's fundamental.

Information on Meta Stack Exchange states I can ask anything related to the Stack Exchange websites, its communities and some other stuff, but I have questions such as this about just asking questions which is not directly connected to Stack Exchange.

The FAQ doesn't satisfy me completely. Where were the FAQ asked? Was it here?

If this question is legitimate (Not the greatest questions you've seen... I know) in the Meta Stack Exchange community then I can be more specific. I'm new to this and just trying to get to know how and what I ask in here.

Comment: You ask questions about asking questions in the question answering software that is Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange. Any questions?

Comment: @Machavity well, it's questionable..

Comment: Did you just ask a question about asking questions about asking questions?

Comment: @Machavity Can you explain please

Comment: Your question - to me - is rather unclear. What type of question do you want to ask? Do you want to ask "how to ask this question without being downvoted instantly?", "what's the core of a good question?" or what?

Comment: What FAQ are you talking about?

Comment: So you weren't sure if you could ask questions about asking questions, but you did know that you could ask questions about asking question about asking questions (since you asked such a question).  Wouldn't it be odd that you could ask if you could ask about asking about asking questions, but not actually ask questions about asking questions?

Comment: Too much meta...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchange is the site for questions about the Stack Exchange family of sites.

You can definitely ask questions about asking questions. Many users do that every day here.
The most common example is the site-recommendation type of question: "on which Stack Exchange site can I ask about X?"

However, on all Stack Exchange sites, we expect you to have made some effort first. We expect that users have first tried to figure things out for themselves. This holds on Meta Stack Exchange as much as on any other Stack Exchange site.

So - before asking anything here, search. See if it hasn't been asked before.  Check the [help center](/help) and the [FAQ](/q/7931/). If, after searching, things are still unclear - then ask. State the problem as clearly as you can, show us what you found when trying to solve it, and explain why these resources did not help you.

You mentioned the FAQ, and if you find something in the FAQ unclear, this is what we expect. We'll be glad to clarify any point in the FAQ, and maybe even update it. But we expect that you've tried to find out for yourself first.

As a side note, Jon Skeet once wrote a blog post about [writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints). Although it is aimed at Stack Overflow, you will also find most of it useful when asking questions on other Stack Exchange sites too - including Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

> I have questions such as this about just asking questions which is not directly connected to Stack Exchange.

The way I interpret this is you essentially want to ask about general social protocols / communication strategies when asking questions (and by "asking questions" I don't mean posting questions here, I mean how to form inquiries in social situations in real life or elsewhere).

Without knowing exactly what you want to ask about it's hard to give specifics, but if your issue deals with a specific field, it *might* be appropriate for a site dedicated to that field.

For example:

- Many sites have a `terminology` tag. If you could reduce your problem to something more specific, like particular terminology that you are confused about, you could perhaps frame it that way.
- If you have grammar / syntax problems when constructing questions, there are quite a few language sites (for English there is [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) as well as [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)).
- If your issue is, say, proper etiquette when making an inquiry in the workplace there is [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com), or if it's in an academic context there is [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Those are just some select examples, but the point is: If you can reduce your communications question to a smaller, more concrete problem, or at least frame it as being specific to a certain field, you may very well be able to find a site that is appropriate.

If you *think* you find an appropriate site but are not sure, you can also always ask for topic clarification on that site's individual meta.

---

It's possible that I've completely misinterpreted your post. The other way to interpret it is you're trying to find out where to ask questions about specific sites, as opposed to the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

For *that*, each site has its own meta, specific to that site. You can access it by selecting "Help" from the nav bar then choosing "Meta", or by opening the dropdown menu under the logo in the nav bar and visiting the meta from there. For example, https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/ has a corresponding meta at https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/.

So, for example, if you visit the Cooking site and want to find out more about what's on topic there, clarify a FAQ entry (note that most communities have their *own* FAQ), etc. you can ask on the Cooking Meta site.

The individual site metas are good, because while there is a general philosophy shared among all SE sites, individual communities still have flexibility and have their own rules, and asking on the individual site's meta is the best way to find out what that specific community thinks.