# Can a meta site be used to formulate a question? If so, how do I do it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, per-site-meta

According to a comment on the question [Is the education system in Finland particularly good?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/is-the-education-system-in-finland-particularly-good), it's okay to formulate a question on a Meta site. I asked the question [Should there be a question on intuition for $0.999\dots = 1$?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30428/should-there-be-a-question-on-intuition-for-0-999-dots-1) but it got a score of -9. Somebody asked the question [Do we want a reference question about the basic rules of chess?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/do-we-want-a-reference-question-about-the-basic-rules-of-chess) except that it was about whether an already existing question should remain. I also once saw a question on Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange that was moved from its Meta site, that I can no longer find.

It seems that some people can find a way of formulating a question on a Meta site that gets accepted by other people. How can I learn how to do that? I'm not an expert in anything. I'm wondering if I just don't have enough of the right knowledge and experience to have any hope of that. According to kcrisman's answer to my question at [How do I ask a good question?](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/how-do-i-ask-a-good-question), sometimes a question is not well accepted because there aren't enough users who have the skills to answer it. Do you think that maybe the same goes for some of the questions for formulating a question?

I know it appears to be promoting my own questions but what am I supposed to do? Of all the questions about a question that there are, it's so much easier for me to track down the ones that were either asked by me or were about one I asked. Other people don't seem to be having a problem with my question [How do I ask a good question?](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/how-do-i-ask-a-good-question) even though it seems to be promoting my own questions.

I know that if I didn't believe the question [Should there be a question on intuition for $0.999\dots = 1$?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30428/should-there-be-a-question-on-intuition-for-0-999-dots-1) or the question [What are the rules of chess in a nutshell?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/what-are-the-rules-of-chess-in-a-nutshell) were worthy of asking, it would work better not to ask them even though I would have less information from which I could make this question more useful. Maybe I made a mistake asking the one at [Should there be a question on intuition for $0.999\dots = 1$?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30428/should-there-be-a-question-on-intuition-for-0-999-dots-1) but now that I asked it, I might as well refer to it. If I had a real good point to make in this question, I probably could have made it some other way by asking a totally different question. Maybe I wouldn't have thought of it but maybe after enough time of trying things and making mistakes, I will become so much better at thinking of things.

Comment: Some sites do have question sandboxes, which are explicit posts where you can have potential questions reviewed before asking, but most don't; what I found to be the best way is to ask in the site's chat room.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I ask questions about asking questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292479/282094) and (wanting a better example) "[don't ask if you can ask, just ask (assuming it's on-topic, well written, etc.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217888/282094)". Also, [tag:site-recommendation] is another matter altogether, but you should give the gist of your question.

Comment: Timothy,  there are a couple of related tags over on Stack Overflow: [mentoring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mentoring) and [quality-improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-improvement). Unfortunately the discontinued mentoring program didn't extend to other sites.

Comment: @Rob Not a duplicate. That question is about refining one's intended question *here on Meta.SE*, while this question is about doing so on per-site metas.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Do you mean that question was about asking any question in general, not asking about whether a specific proposed question belongs? I hadn't even figured that out myself.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I made typo in my previous comment on this question. I meant to say I think that question is about asking questions in general whereas this question is the question of whether you can sometimes write a question on a meta site of a Stack Exchange website to formulate an individual question for that Stack Exchange website. I really don't think this question is a duplicate. I don't think it's worth closing either. I already wrote this question the best possible way I can. Otherwise it will never get any answers.

Comment: @Timothy Definitely agree; voting to reopen

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I think you're right. However, I just figured out another possible reason some people may think this question is a duplicate. Maybe they think it's a question about asking questions on a meta site. Maybe they assume that question already had an answer that gave a really good guideline on how to ask questions including questions for formulating another question because a question is still a question whether it's on a main Stack Exchange website or a meta site. However, I think any to that question that gives a complete guide on how to ask any questions of any sort

Comment: would be far too long. I guess this question was useful after all for those who are interested in the special case of writing a question to formulate another question so that it can get a detailed answer on that very specific matter.

Comment: Looks like this [got reviewed "Leave Closed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/70820). I'd suggest making a new question here, tagged [tag:discussion] [tag:meta] [tag:reopen-closed] asking that this be reopened and explaining why.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That would itself be a question for formulating another question. I guess some people can figure out how to do that properly. However, I don't think I can figure out how to do that. I tried asking the question https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30428/should-there-be-a-question-on-intuition-for-0-999-dots-1 and it got a score of -9. I feel like I cannot ask that question until after this question gets answered because that question would be a question for formulating a question but this question is about whether I can formulate a question and how to do

Comment: that. That answer would actually render the question for formulating this question unnecessary although it may help with situations similar to your suggestion of asking about this question in another question. This question is very unique in that unlike the other questions that seem worthy asking another question specifically about that question, this question has a special reason not to; this vary question itself is about writing one question that's specific to another question. A question about this question would be about only one question whereas an answer to this question would give a

Comment: general guideline on when one question can be used to formulate another question. People don't always think things through carefully. That may have happened in the review. Just because a whole lot of research got done on so many things doesn't mean everything that could have been researched has already been researched. I think the bystander effect in research is real. Sometimes when people so heavily overrely on what other people think is true, false rumours spread. In the past, the restaurant where I work was disorganized. I think the workers were in a panicky scramble to follow the boss'

Comment: orders of being efficient enough scrambling to figure out a way to get their own job done when they were affected by the other workers and thought the boss had a reason for laying out the plan the way they did. Maybe they thought it's because some people actually have the method of thinking that it's part of the job. The bosses thought they weren't happening because the workers weren't reporting them. They were probably feeling stuck causing other problems and thinking the boss could figure out that that's how the job works whereas the bosses were unaware of it and thought they weren't

Comment: happening. Sometimes those who think for themselves without relying on what other people think can do a better job like I did when I slowly and gradually got my restaurant a lot more organized than before. With the right technique, people will actually be checking how one another works using a slow discovery learning approach and determine through an advanced technique of interaction what's going and how to function better and get so much more organized. However, sometimes people are so sure of how other people are working that they don't even check and they think it's working when it's not.

Comment: Some people may also be at the other extreme thinking other people cannot figure out how to work so they have to tell them how to work, not realizing there is a way for them to work with other people that actually works, using an advanced technique to continuously debate with one another how each person should work and always passing along information in a broken telephone like matter using the advanced technique. With the advanced technique, when ever one person hears another person say they think something is true even if they previously thought it was unlikely to be true, they will be like

Comment: "The fact that they said it is a sign that new evidence came giving them a reason to think it." and then they will all agree on what they think is true. Also, I cannot yet ask another question on this website. Eventually, I might ask a question asking for advice for an advanced technique on in general when to ask a question for formulating another question or for asking any question.